# mobile camera won't open with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia on ios chrome browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, camera, webrtc, navigator

The following code is working fine on android mobile device, However on IOS (iPhone) on Chrome browser the following is not working as expected. I saw a lot of problems regarding this issue on IOS devices. Someone has any idea how to fix this issue?

customCamera.js:

```
   this.Play = function (_this, stream) {

            _this.stream = stream;
            console.log(stream)
            videoElement.srcObject = stream;

            videoElement.onloadedmetadata = function () {

                // console.log("mediadataloaded");
                try{
                    videoElement.play();
    
                    window.videoElement = videoElement
    
                    animate();
                } 
                catch(error) {
                    console.error("Failed to acquire camera feed: " + error.name);
                    alert("Failed to acquire camera feed: " + error.name);
                }
                
            };
        };


async start() {

        var _this = this;

        (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || alert("No navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia exists.");

        try {

            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                // audio: false,
                video: {
                    facingMode: _this.options.facingMode,
                    width: _this.options.width,
                    height: _this.options.height,
                    frameRate: _this.options.frameRate
                }
            });
            this.currentStream = stream;
            window.stream = stream
            _this.Play(_this, stream);


        } catch (err) {
            if(err.name === "OverconstrainedError") {
                alert("Device dont have a back camera !")
            }
        }

    }
```

I use this "customCamera.js" in my main.js file on regular video tag:

main.js

```
import Camera from './customCamera.js';

 const deviceCamera = new Camera(videoElement, {
      onFrame: async () => {
            facingMode: "environment"
        });

        deviceCamera.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 12, Chrome version 19.0.4515 and below doesn't support camera but works fine in Safari.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).